# Excel formula to find "WORDS" (multiple variables) and place them in corresponding categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a download of transcations with amount and description.  I'm trying to search for words in the "description" column that will put the data I need into appropiate colums.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(F$1,$D449)),"",$B449)
```

Is a great formula but it only allows to search using the 1 word or phrase in the column header.  It does not allow for multiple variables.

- I have **multiple words** that I need to find in the description column.  For example:  "Deposit" or "payment" or "INV" or "Interest" are all types of revenue I want to appear in 1 column.  If those words do not exist, returning null.  This column is titles Revenue.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Be careful in searching for words, "interest" is also in 'interesting', and INV can be embedded in many.
REGEX may be something that can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIF` with wildcards to check if each of your keywords appear in the description.  Use `OR` to check whether any of them were found.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(D2,"*"&$F$2:$F$5&"*")),B2,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Jan mentioned in the comment section if you are looking for an exact match, then you cannot use `SEARCH` or `COUNTIF` as it is in @kevin's answer. Here is an array version assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tag listed in the question. Put in `C2` the following formula (*formula 1*):

```
=LET(desc,B2:B10, keywords,F2:F5, BYROW(desc, LAMBDA(x,
  TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(keywords, 1-ISNA(XMATCH(keywords, TEXTSPLIT(x,, " "))),
   "NULL")))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]
As you can see the word `Deposito` doesn't provide a match for `Deposit`.

The previous solution preserves the order of the **Keywords** column, not the order of appearance in column **B** (**Description**). If you want to preserve the order of appearance, then you can use the formula in column **D Alternative** (*formula 2*):

```
=LET(desc, B2:B10, keywords, F2:F5, BYROW(desc, LAMBDA(x, 
 LET(idx, XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(x, , " "),keywords),
  TEXTJOIN(",",,IFERROR(INDEX(keywords,TOROW(idx, 2)),"NULL"))))))
```

The *formula 1*, use `BYROW` to iterate over `desc` values. For each value of `desc` (`x`) splits it via `TEXTSPLIT` by row using as a delimiter `" "`. Then it uses `XMATCH` to find the index positions of the split values in `keywords`. The nonmatch condition is indicated by `NA` so we can filter `keywords` values via `FILTER` function. `TEXTJOIN` function is used to concatenate the `keywords` results for multiple matches.

In *formula 2* to keep the order of appearance we interchange the `XMATCH` arguments. Now we are looking for the index positions of keywords in the split `desc`. Now we filter the index positions (`idx`) by non-`NA` values via `TOROW` function and we use `INDEX` function to find the corresponding `keywords` values. For the case of non-match, we get an error, therefore we use `IFERROR` to return `NULL`.

**Note**: For a large dataset you can optimize the search via `XMATCH` for *formula 2* having the `keyword` values sorted, then set the input argument `search_mode` to `2` for ascending order or `-2` for descending order. For more information check [XMATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312) specification.